# How are desired specs decided upon in a common emitter amplifier circuit? (beginner)

Tags: bjt, common-emitter, specifications

I have been reading up on amplifier circuits recently out of curiosity and would like to attempt designing my own. However, I would first like to understand how various amplifier specifications are decided upon. I've copied an online example for the purposes of an easier explanation:

**Problem**: Design a common-emitter amplifier using the 2N3904 transistor that meets the following specs:

- Ic = 2mA
- Vcc = 30V
- Av = -50 V/V
- Rin = 4kΩ
- RL = 1kΩ
- Vin = 10mV @ 10kHz

I understand that various equations are then drawn and implemented in order to solve for the remaining values, but would like to learn how these provided values were determined.

I have looked through the 2N3904 transistor datasheet in detail but fail to understand which parts contribute towards deciding Ic and Vcc. I don't have formal training as an electrical engineer, so your patience would be greatly appreciated.

(Source: [https://www2.seas.gwu.edu/~ece20/Spring2011/labs/tutorials/Tutorial5_Designing_Common_Emitter_Amplifier.pdf](https://www2.seas.gwu.edu/%7Eece20/Spring2011/labs/tutorials/Tutorial5_Designing_Common_Emitter_Amplifier.pdf))

Comment: I'd like you to write a little bit about how you'd start out thinking about the above specifications. You've written nothing about where you would start. Do you see anything useful as a starting place? You've got a list of specifications. Can you think of a "next step," perhaps a quantitative computation or a quantitative comparison? Something that might help you decide some detail or exclude some possibility or test the specifications themselves to see if they are consistent and logical? Anything at all? Expose your mind to examination. It's no harm or foul to be wrong. At times we all are.

Comment: Your link tells in great detail each step in your example. Is  it too much info?

Comment: Just one hint: It is not possible simply "to solve for the remaining values".  Even with the known requirements you have some degree of freedom to choose between some design alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

The quiescent current usually comes from other considerations.

---

One possibility is if this is a pre-amplifier. Here, the goal is usually to set things up so that the BJT's noise contribution is minimized with respect to the source noise. There's a thing called a "noise figure" which expresses the noise added by the BJT amplifier stage as compared to the noise generated by the source. In a perfect situation, the BJT adds no noise and the noise figure is \$0\:\text{dB}\$. But, of course, reality means that is never true. The BJT has Johnson noise for it's base resistance and shot noise for currents crossing its PN junction and these add to the situation. In a case like this, the quiescent current (other particulars about the BJT being the same) is chosen with higher values used for lower source impedances and lower values used for higher source impedances.

In broad terms, you want the quiescent collector current to be somewhere between \$\frac{300\:\text{mV}}{R_{_\text{SOURCE}}}\$ and \$\frac{3\:\text{V}}{R_{_\text{SOURCE}}}\$. A good guess might be to simply use \$\frac{1\:\text{V}}{R_{_\text{SOURCE}}}\$. If the source impedance is about \$600\:\Omega\$ (one of many audio standards) then you might find \$I_{_\text{Q}}\approx 1.7\:\text{mA}\$ as an option. Finally, if the source resistance is more than a few tens of k-Ohm, a JFET is probably a better choice for noise reasoning.

The above paragraph is "nearly useless" if you are serious about noise, though. There's a very well-written book on the topic that dedicates chapter 5 to a good discussion covering noise and BJTs: [Berkhard Vogel's 2nd edition of *"Balanced Phono-Amps: An Extension to the 'The Sound of Silence' Editions"*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07Q5F53G9). This is the kind of go-to-book you want to have on-hand, so that don't miss something important. In fact, I think that book is of unique value and a must-have.

---

Another way to go ignores the noise issues and instead focuses on voltage gain variations due to the signal. Signal-dependent gain variation is another way of saying *distortion*. And low-distortion is another possible goal. In this case, there are other computations.

The formula is a little long and it ignores details, even then. Simplified still further, you can very roughly approximate it with only the output impedance, gain magnitude, and desired THD. About \$I_{_\text{Q}}\approx\frac{\mid A_v\mid\,V_T}{2\,R_{_\text{C}}\,\sqrt{{T\! \small HD}}}\$. For example, if \$R_{_\text{C}}=2.7\:\text{k}\Omega\$, \$\mid A_v\mid=50\$, and \${T\! \small HD}=1\%\$, then I'd work out about \$I_{_\text{Q}}\approx 2.4\:\text{mA}\$.

The fuller version takes into account the input signal, though, and for your case with the peak-to-peak input being \$v_{_\text{PP}}\approx 28.3\:\text{mV}\$ (assuming the spec is RMS) I find \$I_{_\text{Q}}\approx 3.1\:\text{mA}\$, instead.

---

Your example specifications don't really make sense to me. The relatively large \$V_{_\text{CC}}\$ and small \$I_{_\text{Q}}\$ suggest a somewhat large-valued collector resistor. But the output load impedance, \$R_{_\text{L}}\$, means that most of the open-loop gain is divided out quickly. Which means the stage gain has to be a lot higher to compensate -- so much higher that you'd almost have to run a grounded-emitter. But that means low input impedance (too far below that of the specification) and also, without NFB, also distortion -- a lot of it.

I'm just a hobbyist, though. Hopefully better folks than I will chip in and help.

Answer (score 1):

> I would first like to understand how various amplifier specifications are decided upon.

**Great design only comes from learning how to make good specs** *and then how to derive it, yet they teach, the other way around.*   (Either way, you need both)

Rather than follow the bad design example in the textbook, look at the CE, Common Emitter H-biased NPN in this classic Instrument : The Tektronix 492 Spectrum Analyzer, then understand the specs from the design.

[image]
See box 2

- Zin = 47 Ohms + re = 50 Ohms
  Collector to centre tapped coil ~ > 100nH is high impedance and lossless
- Voltage gain is 50% of 1k/50 = 10 with one 50 Ohm load
- Zout is ~ 3 Ohms due to collector negative feedback.  so it can drive four 50 Ohm loads [box 3] each with a gain of 2. This dual supply may have noise and is filtered by the 100 Ohm 0.022 caps

Common Emitter or CE Amps are basic simple ccts for general purpose voltage gain which is a product of current gain and impedance ratios. Often one uses a 50 Ohm Sig. gen. but not always, so source impedance must be specified to determine input attenuation and AC coupling

We can compute some sort of power gain, but here we will only examine voltage gain and assume some current gain , hFE from the 2N3904 spec.  (although the 2N5088 is a much better choice for audio due to higher hFE, it was once a gold standard (pun intended because they added gold doping to achieve higher hFE)

For large swings driving a lower impedance than the Rc collector which is your output impedance, is foolish and when the AC load current exceeds your DC collector current the transistor is no longer conducting.

Hence audio amplifiers and Op Amps always have a load much higher than the output impedance. RL>> Zout
(Usually 100x lower driver impedance)  While "maximum power transfer, MPT theory says this occurs when impedances are matched, we aren't dealing with much power here and just want voltage gain. The simple CE amp is more of a "pre-amp" before any power amp, if needed.

Since it is a simple amplifier, it's good for learning but, there are far better choices with differential amps, Op Amps etc. But we won't discuss that.

Also, this example in the lab book is a learning exercise with poor design specs. So it is poor example of a design but rather how to understand bad design  with poor specs like seeing how a 1K load attenuates Rc=4k badly then remembering not to do that again and not stating maximum input because you don't need to centre the collector output DC if you are only driving the AC output to 150mV on a 30Vdc supply.

So let's talk about design choices to see what is needed for a simple design.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

### Modified Design example:

**Input  :** 20 Hz min , 80 mV pp max
**Source impedance:** 1 kΩ
**Output :** 4 Vpp max with a gain of 50
**Vcc:** your choice, but at least 5 to 9 V to minimize distortion at either peak ( cut-off and saturation)

- cutoff is when Ic goes to 0 and NPN collector goes to Vcc, but before this gain have already started to decrease
- saturation is when Vce drops below 0.7V. As this represents max Ic when gain starts to increase before the bottom is cutoff when the collector goes near ground.

---

[image]

to be continued

When the gain, AV is high, the 2nd order harmonic also high due to variation of Vbe to Ic being nonlinear.  This is why NFB is used to reduce gains from 100 open loop to 50 or less with Rcb added to reduce the variation in Vbe.  This is a significant tradeoff improvement.  Albeit no needed for low gains as Vbe stays constant relative to modulating emitter Ie=Ve/Re.

**Advanced design specs include THD, NF , power-up time stabilization time,  and sensitivity analysis to hFE variations and comparisons with Common base designs.**

Comment: Thank you! I believe this will put me in a good position to get started. I also appreciate your thoughts about the importance of good specs in design. I'll let you know if I have further questions about your post.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few considerations which might influence how you bias a BJT in your amplifier.

First up, and most often overlooked, is noise. BJTs have something called a noise figure. I will paraphrase [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise_figure), which says that the noise figure is the decibel representation of "the ratio of actual output noise to that which would remain if the device itself did not introduce noise". In terms of signal to noise ratio (SNR), it's the ratio of input SNR to output SNR.

Obviously some applications will require you to take great care to minimise noise, like a microphone preamplifier. This makes sense when you consider that the gain of a microphone amplifier may be in the hundreds, and any noise present in the early gain stages will also be amplified by that factor.

Others may be less concerned with noise, for example the power output stage of of an audio amplifier (unless you are an audiophile), with a voltage gain of 1. In such cases you'll probably not care about a few extra microvolts of noise.

If you are concerned with noise, then you'll need to use a transistor which is designed to perform well in this respect, and refer to whatever noise figure information is present in the datasheet. For example, the [OnSemi 2N5089 datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/2n5088-d.pdf) tells us that this device has a noise figure of 2dB. Compare that to the 2N3904 noise figure of around 5dB.

That datasheet is unusually good, in that it goes into some great detail about noise performance (and even includes a Spice model), with graphs like this (from page 6):

[image: Noise Figure vs. Ic,Rs]

As you can see, if you wish to minimise noise, then you'll need to operate this transistor in a regime that places it at a favourable point on one of these plots. You can see that collector current would ideally be somewhere just above 200µA.

Another more simple example I can think of is when you're concerned with maximum power transfer, where you require input resistance to equal the source. To engineer a 600Ω input resistance to match with a 600Ω microphone, you require the parallel combination of the base bias resistors to equal 600Ω:

[image: 600Ω input impedance]

The thing hanging off the output will be a big influence. You need to keep the output impedance significantly lower than the input impedance of the next stage, to keep things as linear as possible, and to prevent the next stage from messing up the biasing of this one. This usually equates to making the collector resistance as low as possible.

In most cases it's a good idea to keep all resistances as low as possible (without violating any other constraints you must honour, of course, such as power consumption), since each resistor is a source of noise that worsens as resistance increases.

Regarding gain, I'm sure you are already aware that the bandwidth achieveable by your amplifier is limited by the transistor's foibles, and various other "parasitic" elements present in the system. Gain (-Rc/Re) versus bandwidth is therefore yet another thing to make your life harder. You can't just make Rc a hundred times greater than Re, and expect gain to be -100 all the way up to 60kHz, for your ultrasonic remote control receiver.

You might be tempted to place collector voltage half way between the supplies, but that may not be necessary. If, for example, you only expect 100mV swing at the output, you may place the quiescent output level more or less anywhere you like, which gives you greater freedom of choice of values for Rc and Re.

There are surely other considerations that define the various "target characteristics" of any amplifier, but that should give you some idea of how you might begin to address them.

Comment: Why do you think it is important to maximize power delivery in the case of a 600 Ohm input source? What's your thinking here? And why do you argue that a relatively low load impedance implies distortion? It attenuates, but why does it distort? I'm not sure I follow these two.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply it's necessary to maximise power delivery from a 600Ω source. I think it might be desirable in some cases, and this was an example of how such a requirement can influence the design.
The distortion thing, I get your point. My thinking was that for any appreciable output swing, this design is fairly non-linear to start with, and a load that upsets a carefully positioned operating point will not help.

Comment: Power delivery is pretty much an output requirement. So I might be driving a \$600\:\Omega\$ headphone and I want to galvanically isolate the headphone. So I would use a  \$600\:\Omega:600\:\Omega\$ audio transformer. In this case, I ***do*** want to maximize the power delivery into the headphone, as power directly translates to moving air which is how we hear things. I'd lose 75% of the power with the isolation. But it's the best I can do. In general, while intermediate (inside the amp) loads *can* distort if there is an important non-linear (diode) aspect to the load, they usually don't.

Comment: @SimonFitch Thank you so much for your detailed response! I'm going to read through this a few times (and will likely return with more questions for the community)